# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest' after Android Studio 2.2 update

Tags: android, android-studio

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute activity#com.facebook.FacebookActivity@theme value=(@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar) from AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-72
>       is also present at [com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.16.0] AndroidManifest.xml:32:13-63 value=(@style/com_facebook_activity_theme)
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-28:75 to override

---

### Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.droid.bdapp.test">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


    <application
        android:name="com.test.app.app.AppBaseApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <activity android:name="com.test.app.ui.activities.WelcomeActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.test.engine.reader.view.test5"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"></activity>

        <activity android:name="com.test.app.ui.activities.test1" />
        <activity android:name="com.test.app.ui.activities.test2" />
        <activity android:name="com.test.app.ui.activities.test3" />
        <activity android:name="com.test.app.ui.activities.test4" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What exactly did you try? Give us some info, otherwise we can't help you. How does your manifest look like etc.

Comment: show your manifest?

Comment: @greenhoorn manifest.xml file added

Comment: @Arjunsaini manifest.xml file added

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It's not Android Studio 2.2 upgrade issue, it's FB SDK released yesterday.
For now a solution is to revert to previous FB SDK in **build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.15.0'
}
```

This worked for me, will track the change log and bug list on FB support to see the proper solution.

Comment: I wouldn't revert back to previous FB SDK version. Its better to just remove `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"` since the latest FB SDK 4.16.1 already includes it.

Answer (score 17):

I agree with the other answer, however, I would like to propose another solution.

**Stick with the theme determined by Facebook** by removing `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"` and keep using `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4+'`

---

### Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.droid.bdapp.test">

    <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Facebook wants to `handle` the themes for the webdialog spinners as stated in the `changelog`

> Better handling of themes for webdialog spinners

Ref: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/change-log-4.x#4_16_0

Comment: I think you're solution is better. Just remove `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"` from <activity> and use latest FB SDK version. 4.16.1. You can find the latest sdk version [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads/)

Answer (score 2):

Add the ***compile dependency with the latest version*** of the **[Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads/)** in the build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {

          compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.16.0' //Or 4.16.1

            }
```

**[DeadObjectExceptions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/DeadObjectException.html)**  Bugs fixed .

Comment: latest FB SDK version is 4.16.1 now.

Comment: @kimbaudi Yes yes . but `4.16.0` is stable

Comment: This [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads/) indicates that 4.16.1 is the stable version as of October 7th, 2016

Comment: @kimbaudi Okay .I will use that version .Thanks for mention

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has a new version released 27Sep16.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads/

Most build.gradle files automatically pick up the latest version (as per install instructions). It seems 4.16.0 has a problem for a number of users. To force use of previous version until this is resolved, edit your build gradle to use the previous version.

```
 compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.15.0')
```

I'd expect this to be resolved by Facebook shortly and you can revert your build.gradle to pick up the latest version once more.

Comment: No, just use the latest and remove `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"` since the latest FB SDK already includes it.