# How to solve Facebook tools:replace="android:theme"?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.16.0'
```

My manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
...
    <application
            android:name=".MyApplication"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AutoTheme"
            tools:replace="android:theme">
```

How to solve compile error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute activity#com.facebook.FacebookActivity@theme value=(@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar) from AndroidManifest.xml:69:13-72
    is also present at [com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.16.0] AndroidManifest.xml:32:13-63 value=(@style/com_facebook_activity_theme).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to <activity> element at AndroidManifest.xml:66:9-70:47 to override.
```

Comment: It's showing error on activity tag. You need to remove style or provide  tools:replace="android:theme" to your <activity> tag.  Paste your whole manifest file here.

Comment: It's some error in Facebook SDK v4.16 http://stackoverflow.com/a/39748440/983914

Comment: [just follow this link.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39748440/2017098)
you'll find the answer..

Comment: It seems like we have to either add `tools:replace="android:theme` or remove `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"` from our AndroidManifest.xml file. Both ways worked for me. But which way is preferred? The current Facebook Android SDK version is 4.16.1 and the issue is that manifest merger failed due to [com.facebook.android:facebook-android;sdk:4.16.1] also having `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"`. I believe that removing `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"` is better.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

1) Add `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` to `<manifest>` element at AndroidManifest

2) Add `tools:replace="android:theme"` to (facebook activity) `<activity>`

Here is my manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.company.product" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    ...

    <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      android:name="MyApplication">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            ...
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>

      <!--FacebookActivity-->
      <activity
        tools:replace="android:theme"
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>

        ...

      </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I disagree. There is no need to add `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` to <manifest> and add `tools:replace="android:theme"` to <activity>. Its better to just remove `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"` from the <activity> xml tag since the latest Facebook SDK 4.16.1 already includes it. But either way works, so it doesn't matter from that standpoint.

Comment: @kimbaudi Can you share where you found that information regarding Facebook SDK 4.16.1 including the `android:theme`? Facebook's [official docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android#prerequisites) still recommend adding the `android:theme` attribute.

Comment: Thanks its help me

Comment: Thanks bro, it worked. I wonder what kind of genius develops an SDK that has conflicts for integrating the most basic use case (Login)

Answer (score 7):

Try this.

```
 <activity
                android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```

**Replace to**

```
  <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/com_facebook_activity_theme" />
```

Comment: No need to replace. Just remove `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"`

Answer (score 4):

In your manifest, remove

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

in the FacebookActivity

**Edit:**
Do you use firebase as well? If so, have a look here [Android manifest merger with facebook and firebase libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38101517/android-manifest-merger-with-facebook-and-firebase-libraries)

Comment: FacebookActivity it's class file is in library

Comment: I prefer this solution as well.

Answer (score 3):

You Just have to use the this in your Manifest for the FacebookActivity

```
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            tools:replace="android:theme"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line `@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar`

This will solve your problem

(This way you will avoid manifest propery conflict)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I changed the attribute `android:theme="${appTheme}"` (where `manifestPlaceholders["appTheme"] = "@style/Theme2"` in `build.gradle`) and got a compile error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:processGoogleDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@theme value=(@style/Theme) from AndroidManifest.xml:23:9-42    is also
> present at AndroidManifest.xml:21:9-36 value=(@style/Theme2).
> Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to 
> element at AndroidManifest.xml:15:5-92:19 to override.

I have 3 `AndroidManifest` files. Then I changed `android:theme` in all 3 files.