# I am Trying to use facebook login in My app but I am getting an error that Manifest Merger faild

Tags: android, facebook-login

I am getting this Error.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute activity#com.facebook.FacebookActivity@theme value=(@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar) from AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-72
>       is also present at [com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.35.0] AndroidManifest.xml:32:13-63 value=(@style/com_facebook_activity_theme).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:9-35:20 to override.

This is my MainActivity.java file
    package com.example.advanced.loginactivity;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;


 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 private CallbackManager callbackManager;
 @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);


    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    // App code
                    Log.d("Success", "Login");
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // App code
                    Log.d("Cancel", "Login Cancelled");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    // App code
                    Log.d("Error", "An Error Occured");
                }});
}


  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent        data) {
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}


}
```

This is my AndroidManifest.XML file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    >
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>

</application>
```

This is my activity_main.xml file

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.advanced.loginactivity.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/facebook_sign_in_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my build.gradle(Module: app) file

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.advanced.loginactivity"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'

}
```

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39786339/5492515 answer

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to revert to previous **FB SDK** in **build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
// ...
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.15.0'
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to downgrade the dependecies version, since it works fine with the last version com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)

Answer (score 0):

delete this line: android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>


    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity

    <!-- If you want the custom tabs when the facebook website is oppened -->
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

You'll see that with custom tabs enabled the facebook website will open with a tab in the top and it will occupy the whole screen. Without this the website will open like a pop up and you can still see the app in the background if you look at the corners.

Or **if you want to keep this line** you need to add tools:replace="android:theme" in your manifest. But I see no reason to keep this line (correct me if I am wrong).

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            tools:replace="android:theme"/>
```

For [facebook login guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android).

**ADITIONAL**

An additional tip while working with facebook login, you will notice that when you added the facebook dependecie, com.android.support:appcompat-v7:... gives a warning saying that you have dependecies with different versions. You need to override this dependencie in order to get rid of this error

```
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
```